# 'DefaultMeta' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following cs50 tutorial lecture04 from which I get the following error

ERROR:- 'DefaultMeta' object is not iterable,
please check my code I think the problem is starts from if the statement but I am not able to solve the issue please help

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFIER_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def indexapp():
    railway = Railway.query.all()
    return render_template("indexapp.html", Railway=Railway)

@app.route("/book", methods=["POST"])
def book():
    """ BOOK A Railway """
    #Get Form Information

    name = request.form.get("name")
    try:
        railway_id = int(request.form.get("railway_id"))
    except ValueError:
        return render_template("error.html", message="Invalid Railway Number.")
    #Make Sure the Railway Exists
    railway = Railway.query.get(flight_id)
    if railway is None:
        return render_template("error.html", message="No Such Railway with this id.")

    #ADD Passenger
    
    passenger = Passenger(name=name, railway_id=railway_id)
    db.session.add(passenger)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("sucess.html")
```

Comment: Replace `flight_id` with `railway_id` in row `railway = Railway.query.get(flight_id)`

Answer (score 2):

```
passenger = Passenger(name=name, railway_id=railway_id)
db.session.add(passenger) # on this line ensure that the passenger object is written correctly with the similar alphabetical cases.
```

Answer (score -2):

You do not declare

> "flight_id"

. If it is from model then enclose it in comma.

```
railway = Railway.query.get("flight_id")
```

Try this.

Comment: The function `get` of the `query` object only accepts an `ident` based on the `primary key` of the model and returns an instance or `None`. See the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get).